# Uncaught runtime errors: * is not a function

Tags: reactjs

When I run my React code I get makeStory is not a function.

Here is the parent component called Madlib

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import UserForm from "./UserForm";
import Story from "./Story";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid/dist";

const Madlib = () => {
  const [story, setStory] = useState([]);
  const [showStory, setShowStory] = useState(false);

  const makeStory = (newStory) => {
    setStory((story) => [...story], { ...newStory, id: uuid() });
  };

  return (
    <div className="Madlib">
      <h1>Madlibs</h1>
      {showStory ? (
        <Story story={story[0]} />
      ) : (
        <UserForm setShowStory={setShowStory} makeStory={makeStory} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Madlib;
```

Here is the child component called UserForm

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./UserForm.css";

const UserForm = ({ setShowStory, makeStory }) => {
  const initialState = {
    noun: "",
    noun2: "",
    adjective: "",
    color: "",
  };
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialState);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData((formData) => ({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    makeStory({ ...formData });
    setShowStory(true);
    setFormData(initialState);
  };

  return (
    <div className="UserForm">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          id="noun"
          type="text"
          name="noun"
          placeholder="noun"
          value={formData.noun}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          id="noun2"
          type="text"
          name="noun2"
          placeholder="noun2"
          value={formData.noun2}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          is="adjective"
          type="text"
          name="adjective"
          placeholder="adjective"
          value={formData.adjective}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          id="color"
          type="text"
          name="color"
          placeholder="color"
          value={formData.color}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <button className="button">Get Story</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserForm;
```

I am passing the function, makeStory, from Madlibs to UserForm but I can't figure out why I'm still getting the error the makeStory is not a function. I have destructured props in the child component to have setShowStory, makeStory.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra set of parentheses around the spread operator.

It should be:

```js
const makeStory = (newStory) => {
  setStory((story) => [...story, { ...newStory, id: uuid() }]);
};
```

Remove the extra parentheses around `[...story, { ...newStory, id: uuid() }]` to correctly update the `story` state with the new story object.

Comment: I updated the makeStory function. However, I'm still getting the same error as before.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. I wasn't importing the right component into my App.js file.

Answer (score 0):

**You should spread the stories array (the current state) and then add the new story object to it. This way, you maintain the previous stories and add a new one to the array.**

```
const makeStory = (newStory) => {
  setStory((stories) => [...stories, { ...newStory, id: uuid() }]);
};
```